# Несколько компонентов на один маршрут Vue-Router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Мне бы хотелось использовать разные компоненты для одного маршрута в зависимости от параметров этого маршрута. Чтобы была возможность переходить по данному адресу и попадать или на валидный компонент или на компонент ошибки. Можно ли это осуществить? Не хотелось бы делать это в глобальном хуке beforeEach. Есть ли хорошая практика для таких случаев? Спасибо!

routes.js

```
const routes = [
    {name: 'lesson', path: 'lesson:id', components: { lesson: Lesson, error: E404 }, props: {
       lesson: true,
       error: false
       }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Хорошая практика это использовать инструменты для того, для чего они предназначены. Роутер - для роутинга и логики связанной с *роутингом*.

Ваш вопрос связан с логикой отображения.

Вы можете создать что то вроде прокси компонента. Роутер всегда открывает этот компонент. И в этом компоненте будет логика отвечающая за отображение необходимого состояния (вероятнее всего это другой компонент.

#### router.js

```
const routes = [
    {
       name: 'lesson', 
       path: 'lesson:id', 
       component: Proxy, 
       props: {
           lesson: true,
           error: false
       }
    }
]
```

#### Proxy.vue

```
<template>
    <template v-if="lesson">
        <Lesson></Lesson>
    </template>
    <template v-else-if="error">
        <Error></Error>
    </template>
    <template v-else></template>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "Proxy",
    props: {
      lesson: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      },

      error: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```